# Using beautifulsoup to extract text between the start of paragraph tag and a line break

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have the following HTML document

```
<p>
  "Year: 1932"
   <br>
   <br>
  "Total Share : 0.5 Lakhs (Pure Estimate)"
  <br>
  <br>
  "Verdict"
</p>
```

I am currently using BeautifulSoup to obtain the other elements in HTML, but I am unable to get a way to get these lines as is. I am getting them in a single line.

Comment: Can you please give an example of output how you want ?

Comment: Year: 1932, Total Share : 0.5 Lakhs (Pure Estimate), Verdict. This is the ideal output that I am looking for.

Comment: I have added a solution please check it. And **response_data** should have HTML document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response_data = <Your html tags>

soup_data = BeautifulSoup(response_data, features="html5lib")
string_data = soup_data.find('p').text.strip().replace("\n", ",").replace("\"", "").split(',')
data_list=[]
for strng in string_data:
    if strng.strip():
        data_list.append(strng.strip())

print(data_list)
```

Comment: I am getting an error @krishna when trying to create beautifulsoup object.

Comment: **FeatureNotFound:** **Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: html5lib. Do you need to install a parser library?**

Comment: yeah you need to install that library.

Comment: Can't we use html.parser library instead of html5lib? @krishna

Comment: You can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to close the br like that `<br/>`

Comment: Actually, the mentioned html is a part of website which I am trying to scrape using beautifulsoup. I cannot change the structure of the webpage.